# Проверка на зажатость Кнопки в Kivy Python

Tags: python, kivy

я хочу сделать так, чтобы если пользователь зажал кнопку, то постоянно прибавлялось значение.
main.py

```
class Game(Screen):
    def count_up
        self.ids.player.y += 10
```

main.kv

```
Button: 
    text: '>'
        on_press: root.count_up()
```

То-есть, персонаж находится на координатах x=0 y=0.
у меня получается так что каждый клик прибавляет 10 к координате y.
У меня не происходит постоянного прибавление к координате, при зажатии кнопки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давно пользовался киви. У них есть Clock.

```
class Foo(object):
    def start(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.callback, 0.5)

    def callback(self, dt):
        print('In callback')

# A Foo object is created and the method start is called.
# Because no reference is kept to the instance returned from Foo(),
# the object will be collected by the Python Garbage Collector and
# your callback will be never called.
Foo().start()

# So you should do the following and keep a reference to the instance
# of foo until you don't need it anymore!
foo = Foo()
foo.start()
```

Думаю этот пример может помочь.